# Report test summary of julia package from Travis to my README

Tags: julia, travis-ci

I have a Julia project on GitHub which uses Travis for CI tests. At the end of the `Pkg.test(coverage=true)` command from `.travis.yml` there is a test summary for all my tests inside the job log, looking like this:

```sh
Test Summary:            | Pass  Error  Total
All Tests                |   11      6     19
  Simple Tests           |    3             3
  Other Tests            |    8      6     14
    Some specific test   |    2      2      4
      1.15               |    2      2      4
      5.0                |           2      2
    More tests           |    6             6
```

Is there a way to report the number of passing/failing tests to my `README.md`? Maybe similar to the badges included with `[![Build Status](https://travis-ci.com/User/ProjectName.svg?branch=master)](https://travis-ci.com/User/ProjectName)`

The basic idea is, that my tests will probably still error for the near future, but the number of errors should reduce and I want it to be visible on test reports.

Comment: IMHO, README.md is not the right place to have/track this information, since it is a detail only relevant to the package maintainer. It should be fairly simple to quickly check the Travis logs.

Comment: BTW, I don't think there is a simple technical solution to get what you want, but I might be wrong.

Comment: I might do this using codcov instead - that is, use `@test_broken` for the tests that are still failing, then report test coverage rather than number of tests that fail. You can get badges for, say, 70% test coverage, and that number will go up as you fix broken tests https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Test/index.html#Broken-Tests-1

Comment: You could log the tests during the test, scrape the log file, and then have a Julia script that reads it, edits the readme, and lastly auto-commits the updated stats on tests.

Comment: I think the way logankilpatrick suggested is the way to go for me.